# How to print in the output only the line of a detected string in a file

Tags: c, file, pointers

Let's assume that i have a file that contains information in each line. In this format :
Name of the information : Information.
There is many informations in this file.
I managed to get the name of the information in my code using "strstr". But the problem is when i printf. It outputs until the EOF (End of file) not until the end of line (\n).
The question is : How can i get the complet line when i find the string. What to do if the string is found many times ? Thanks

````
char* p; // Pointer
content=charge_file("cpuinfo.txt"); // This function charge the cpu informations in a file called cpuinfo.txt
    p=strstr(content,"processor"); // I'm looking for the String "processor"

       while(p!=NULL){ // While not end of file
       p++;
       if(p=strstr(p,"processor")){
       count++; // New processor found
        }
      printf("%d",count);// number of processors  
       }```
````

Comment: So you are trying to read `/proc/cpuinfo` and count the number of processors?

Comment: Is C++ an option?

Comment: I'm trying to read cpuinfo.txt that already contains what informations like /proc/cpuinfo. No c++ is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it quite easily if all you are seeking to do is compare the beginning of each line and then keep a count of the number of times your comparison matches a search string. The approach is to read each line into a sufficiently sized fixed buffer with `fgets()` and then make a simple comparison of the beginning of the line to your search string with `strncmp`. If the comparison tests true, increment a counter.

For example you could do something similar to the following where the filename to read is provide by the first argument to the program and the term to search the beginning of each line for is provided as the second argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 2048   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC]; /* buffer to hold each line in file */ 
    char *cmpstr = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "processor";    /* compare string */
    size_t cmplen = strlen (cmpstr), nstr = 0;  /* length to compare, count */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : NULL;  /* open file */

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))                   /* read each line */
        if (strncmp (buf, cmpstr, cmplen) == 0)     /* does start match? */
            nstr++;     /* increment count */
    fclose (fp);                                    /* close file */

    printf ("%zu - %s(s)\n", nstr, cmpstr);         /* output results */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** don't skimp on buffer size. You would rather have 100,000 characters too many, than 1 character too few)

**Example Use/Output**

Reading `/proc/cpuinfo` directly you would do:

```
$ ./bin/cmpleadingstr /proc/cpuinfo processor
4 - processor(s)
```

If you want, in addition, to output each of the matching strings, simply include a call to `fputs` for the matching string, e.g.

```
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))                   /* read each line */
        if (strncmp (buf, cmpstr, cmplen) == 0) {   /* does start match? */
            fputs (buf, stdout);                    /* output string */
            nstr++;     /* increment count */
        }
```

**Output With Printed String**

```
$ ./bin/cmpleadingstr /proc/cpuinfo processor
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
processor       : 2
processor       : 3

4 - processor(s)
```

(**note:** newline before total added)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. If you cannot use the `string.h` library for any reason, you can just use a loop for obtaining the search term length as well as the initial comparison.

Answer (score -1):

i believe you should use streaming of the text from the file (look for stream builder) and every time you see the specific char you decide on you can store or use the data. (you try to use it like a json i guess), i mean you should organise the text in a specific way.

hope i was clear enough..

Comment: C has no "stream builder". I hope I was clear enough.